# Deploying a field update to a queue

Tags: workflow, field-update, change-set, queue, workflowrule

When deploying via a change set a Workflow rule that has a field update that Sets the OwnerId to a Queue, I get an error in the destination org: 'Illegal field: OwnerId for lookup value type:Queue'.

[image]

How can I get this workflow rule deployed?

[image]

Comment: You may need to deploy the queue in a separate change set prior to the deployment of the workflow rule as I have had some similar issues with change sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing, was manually creating the field updates to the org.  When I pushed the Workflow after, everything went fine.  It's not a satisfactory answer but it's the approach I was forced to take.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `Case` is selected in the `Supported Objects` section of the `Queue` configuration.

[image: Supported Objects]

You should also be able to query the `QueueSObject` to confirm its existence:

```
SELECT SObjectType FROM QueueSObject WHERE Queue.Name = 'GPS Tier 2 Support'
```

Comment: I did this and it had no effect.

Comment: @dphil for all the relevant queues? It was already set up or it was missing and you had to add it still?

Comment: Yes, one approach I had done was to put the Queues in a separate change set and push them before as well as with.  None of that worked besides manually creating the field update.

Comment: What a PITA. Bummer.